# Handling spring boot rest PUT with multiple parameters

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I am new to Spring boot and have no prior experience in spring boot and I have below requirement

I have an UI with multiple fields ( check boxes, Text fields , drop downs etc). when user edit a record and submit button clicked , my rest service will be called.

Here I need to take the multiple ( almost 10) parameters in my request and save them into database.

and can I declare ENUM values for drop downs?

what is the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is define an object, say `InterfaceState`, that will contain all variations that you mentioned as properties. Construct your object and put it in the body of the request. Server side use:

```
.. @RequestBody("interfaceState") InterfaceState interfaceState ..
```

in the API which handles the request.